# sh: curl: not found even install curl inside k8s pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

It might be simple question but I could not find the proper solution.

I have a Docker image as below.. The things that I would like to do simply run curl command inside kubernetes pod but I received an error as below.. I could not able to exec via bash also.

```
$ kubectl exec -ti hub-cronjob-dev-597cc575f-6lfdc -n hub-dev sh
Defaulting container name to hub-cronjob.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/hub-cronjob-dev-597cc575f-6lfdc -n hub-dev' to see all of the containers in this pod.
/usr/src/app $ curl
sh: curl: not found
```

Tried with bash

```
$ kubectl exec -ti cronjob-dev-597cc575f-6lfdc -n hub-dev bash
 mand in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "8019bd0d92aef2b09923de78753eeb0c8b60a78619543e4cd27069128a30da92": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine AS builder

# Variables from outside
ARG NODE_ENVIRONMENT=development
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENVIRONMENT

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

#Install curl
RUN apk --no-cache add curl -> did not work
RUN apk update && apk add curl curl-dev bash -> did not work

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Build Stage 2
# Take the build from the previous stage
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app /usr/src/app

# run the application
EXPOSE 50005 9183

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:docker" ]
```

Comment: You must install curl yourself in your image, eg: `RUN apk --no-cache add curl`

Comment: You can try your image locally, no reason to deploy it to kubernetes before it is working.

Comment: Only contents after the final `FROM` line are included in the final image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Dockerfile consists of multiple stages, which is also called [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Each `FROM` statement is a new stage and new image. In your case you have 2 stages:

- `builder` where you build you app and install curl
- `second stage` which copies /usr/src/app from `builder` stage

In this case second `FROM node:12-alpine` statement will contain only basic alpine packages, node tools and /usr/src/app which you have copied from the first stage.

If you want to have curl in your final image you need to install `curl` in second stage (after second `FROM node:12-alpine`):

```
FROM node:12-alpine AS builder

# Variables from outside
ARG NODE_ENVIRONMENT=development
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENVIRONMENT

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Do not install 

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Build Stage 2
# Take the build from the previous stage
FROM node:12-alpine

#Install curl
RUN apk update && apk add curl

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app /usr/src/app

# run the application
EXPOSE 50005 9183

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:docker" ]
```

As it was mentioned in comments you can test it by running docker container directly - no need to run pod in k8s cluster:

```sh
docker build -t image . && docker run -it image sh -c 'which curl'
```

It is common to use multi-stage build for applications implemented in compiled programming languages.

1. In the first stage you install all necessary dev tools and compilers and then compile sources into a binary file. Since you don't need and probably don't want sources and developer's tools in a production image you should create a new stage.
2. In the second stage you copy compiled binary file and run it as CMD or ENTRYPOINT. This way your image contains only executable code, which makes them smaller.

Answer (score 2):

We can *add curl* using *apk* in the k8s pod.

***`apk add curl`***

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and is a full 2 years later than a better answer.